# NLTK: Sentiment Analysis and Stemming

Tags: python, stemming

I am working on a code for Sentiment Analysis. Now I would like to use a Stemmer in my code snippet, but when I use print function, the results show that the stemming does not work. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Here is my code snippet:

```
pos_data = []
with open('Positive.txt') as f:  
    for line in f:
        pos_data.append([format_sentence(line), 'pos'])
    for line in f:
        stemmer.stem(pos_data)
print (pos_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to both split the file into lines and potentially split the lines into words (that can be tokenized)

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk import PorterStemmer
>>> test = 'this sentence is just a tester set of words'
>>> test_tokenize = nltk.word_tokenize(test)
>>> test_tokenize
['this', 'sentence', 'is', 'just', 'a', 'tester', 'set', 'of', 'words']
>>> port = PorterStemmer()
>>> for word in test_tokenize:
...     print port.stem(word)
... 
thi
sentenc
is
just
a
tester
set
of
word



with open('Positive.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
        for word in words:
            print port.stem(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not calling the Stemmer API properly as it takes a single token at a time. That means you should tokenize your sentence first. Check out the docs here http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html

Also for future reference you should include full working code, with imports and the stack trace of your error.

```
with open('Positive.txt') as f:  
    for line in f:
        tokens = format_sentence(line).split() # tokenize using spaces
        stem_sentence = ' '.join([stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens])
        pos_data.append([stem_sentence, 'pos'])
```

Comment: Thank you, I did tokenize the sentences in my file like this: